# iOS: can not create custom view on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

**What am I doing?**
I am learning `iOS` by building an app. My requirement shows some transactions on `UITableViewController`

I need to add `header` which I need to design with some specific information and style. I asked [iOS: How do I make custom header section for Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629698/ios-how-do-i-make-custom-header-section-for-table/25629740) and realized that I need to make a custom `UIView`.

Problem is that I can't drag `View` on `UITableViewController`, XCode does not allow me to

[image]

**Problem?**
- If you see this shows not only the `UIView` but the entire `iPhone` screen
- I need to show this on my `UITableViewController`, with now what I have, how can I put the `UIView` as header on my `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **`UIViewController`** rather than a **`UITableViewController`**

I recommend you don't use a `UITableViewController` as there's little advantage as far as I can see, whilst custom views like you're looking for are unnecessarily difficult.

Use a **`UIViewController`** and pull a `UITableView` object (Within the interface builder) on to that view. You can size and position it anywhere you like.

Remember to include the delegates within the header file, like below, and to connect the `UITableView` object delegate to the the viewController.

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```

Screenshot below of a UIViewController within the interface builder and I've added a UITableview object (which is greyed out here) and added a UIView at the top (coloured brown so you can see it clearly).

This of course is just an example, but hope it helps you get the idea.

[image]

Although in the above screen shot I'm using storyboard, though you can do this just the same with a Xib too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was very useful, thanks. I switched from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

The view you've added the labels to is your view controller's main view. You will need to drag a View from your object library (bottom right menu) and add those labels in it. Then link the added view to your ViewController with an IBOutlet. 
After that you can set your tableView's header to be the added view:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

**EDIT:** If you want to do everything in code. Create the custom header view and drag it above your UITableView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053361/2604030

Comment: do I need to add the new `UIView` on the my existing `UITableViewController` (where I want my header)?

Comment: @daydreamer Yes you have to. Try not to mess with the view you've added your labels to.

Comment: I can't drag `View` to `UITableControllerView` in Interface Builder, it doesn't allow me to

Comment: Can you edit the question with a screenshot if your current ViewController state in Storyboard?

Comment: You haven't yet added the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60475/discussion-between-daydreamer-and-sebyddd).