# Show first cell in UITableView just under the Topbar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have an UITableView in a ordinary View controller with the Top-bar visible on an iPhone.
However, as per the screenshot below, the first cell in the table view is behind the Top-bar. How can I make it appear under the Top-bar while on the iPad, which doesn't use the navigation controller, and doesn't have the Top-bar it appears at the top?

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using a UIViewController as opposed to a UITableViewController. Please see this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25630674/2507277) which may help. It allows you to fully customise your view the way you would like it, as UITableViewController can be restrictive - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25630674/2507277

Answer (score 0):

if you use storyboards there is a nice option on the right (see screenshot). it is called extend edges - under top bars. if you clear the checkbox, your problem should be solved.

[image: xcode iphone storyboard]

Comment: i assume you use two different storyboards for iphone and ipad

Comment: Yes, I currently have two different ones, but will try and combine them shortly. Changing that option does not seem to make a difference. Maybe I have done something programmatically in the past, I will first check that.

Comment: ps. I think it is since I moved to AutoLayout with Storyboard, as previous versions of the App do not have the problem. I am also compiling with Xcode 6 GM, so that might also be a factor.