# Placing an UImageView inside ? or outside ? a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to display an image with a tableView like so (see image below).

But I'm not sure about the way to implement the red part :

- is the red part in the header part of the table view ?
- is the red part outside of the table view ?
- is this in a custom cell ?

[image]

PS : Note that the tableView I would like to be with the picture would have various sections.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Create a view and add these image and all element and then add as tableview header

Comment: Use a UIViewController and add a UITableView to the view below where you intend to put the image. Please see this answer which is similar to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/25630674/2507277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's either a header or a custom UITableViewCell because it scrolls with the table. You can implement it either way.

Personally I'd start by making it a cell. That will allow you to use autolayout to easily tackle sizing and dynamic type.

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! I solved this by making a custom cell in the header of the tableView (otherwise (when that was the first row) they were separators lines around this first cell and this was not wanted).

Answer (score 0):

create a custom view as per suthar's comment and add it to the tableview headerview ,
if you have more than one sections than u can use the groupped tableview instead of plain tableview...it becomes more easy..